# How to free up space on a jenkins server hosted in k8s?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-pod, diskspace, persistent-volumes

I have jenkins deployed in my k8s cluster and I've recently had to increase the size of the attached persistent volume . This solved the issue but I am wondering how to manage the space and stop it growing exponentially. When I connected to the pod and had a look around the file system I couldnt identify anything that I could obviously delete like log files. Anyone have any suggestions on what kind of stuff can be safely deleted?